# How to display tooltip / context menu from Run object in (wpf) RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I'm trying to display tooltips and context menus for certain words in a RichTextBox.  Using inlines with a TextBlock was really easy.  I just did:

```
_textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run("some text") { Foreground = Brushes.Orange, ToolTip = "This is a tooltip", ContextMenu = (contextMenu.Items.Count > 0 ? contextMenu : null) }));
```

Unfortunately, when I do the same thing for a RichTextBox like this:

```
var paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run("some text") { Foreground = Brushes.Orange, ToolTip = "my tooltip doesn't work", ContextMenu = (contextMenu.Items.Count > 0 ? contextMenu : null) }));
_richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
```

It doesn't work.  Right clicking gives me the cut/copy/paste menu and hovering doesn't work.  Is there anything I can do to make this work correctly?  If not, is there any better way than just checking mouse position and building contextMenu and ToolTip dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is fairly simple, just set IsDocumentEnabled="True" on the RichTextBox like so:

```
<RichTextBox Name="tbTest" IsDocumentEnabled="True"></RichTextBox>
```